# Align element in toolbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I use the Datatable with Bootstrap 4. To the left of the search field (that is at the top right), I try to put a checkbox.
It's working, but the checkbox is placed completely to the left.

How can I remove all this space?

http://live.datatables.net/folerayu/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following changes,

**css**

```
.samples-toolbars { //override this css with your current css
  float: left;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
#example_filter{
  float: left;
}
```

**override jquery for datatable**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"samples-toolbars">frtip'
  });

  $("div.samples-toolbars").html('<input type="checkbox" id="testDoneInclude" name="testDoneInclude" checked /><label for="testDoneInclude">Test done include</label>');


} );
```

Hope this will work for you.

[image]